# Only getting unique timestamped rows that match interval

Tags: mysql

I have these two tables...

products:

```
id product_id store_id
1  242234     54034
2  224222     83820
3  839202     24224
4  939284     54034
```

pricing:

```
product_id last_update          source
242234     2016-02-11 12:00:00  7
242234     2016-02-12 12:00:00  7
242234     2016-02-13 12:00:00  7
839202     2016-02-14 12:00:00  3
839202     2016-02-15 12:00:00  3
839202     2016-02-16 12:00:00  3
939284     2016-01-08 12:00:00  7
939284     2016-02-15 12:00:00  7
939284     2016-02-16 12:00:00  7
```

I want to get only the `products.id` values whose `pricing.last_update` only have `pricing.last_update` older than 3 days. If there is a row with a more recent update in the pricing table for the `pricing.product_id`, then I want to ignore that `pricing.product_id` entirely.

To do that, I've tried this query, but it still returns ids that have newer entries:

```
SELECT
    pps.id
FROM
    pricing pr
JOIN
    products pps
        ON pps.product_id = pr.product_id
WHERE
    pr.source = 7 AND
    pps.store_id = 54034
GROUP BY
    pps.id
HAVING
    pr.last_update < NOW() - INTERVAL 3 DAY
ORDER BY
    pr.last_update DESC;
```

From the example given, it should only return `pps.id` = `242234` but instead it also returns `939284`.

How would I structure my query for this?

Comment: You're question seems ok, but could you add the result format you expect? Do you want the last from pricing table for each product or the very first price (no matter what the product). And what is the source and store id, what constraint should we think of there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a correlated `not exists` subquery to find the products that don't have any pricing data newer than 3 days; like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  pps.product_id
FROM
  pricing pr
JOIN
  products pps
        ON pps.product_id = pr.product_id
WHERE
    pr.source = 7 
    AND
    pps.store_id = 54034
    AND NOT EXISTS
    (
       SELECT 1 FROM pricing 
       WHERE pps.product_id = product_id
       AND last_update >= NOW() - INTERVAL 3 DAY
    )
ORDER BY
    pr.last_update DESC;
```

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/816a2/4)

Given your sample data this query will only return `pps.id = 242234`

Comment: For my own knowledge: Why use distinct instead of group by? +1 for the `not exists`

Comment: reading the query I thought this was correct, but it still gives both `242234 ` and `939284`

Comment: @davejal I used distinct to make the intent clear; and in my sample fiddle I got the expected result.

Comment: Ooh, I edited the query earlier because I also created an sqlfiddle and tried your query, but it failed, because my structure was different. OP changed his table structure after I created the fiddle.